# htaccess append Google campaign tracking to aliased url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

Sorry for duplicating the thread ([htaccess rewrite URL to append Google campaign tracking causing redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756785/htaccess-rewrite-url-to-append-google-campaign-tracking-causing-redirect-loop)) but the other one requires 50 points to post a comment which I don't have

I have this simple alias in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /contact$
RewriteRule .* /content.php?id=17 [L]
```

and I'm using analytics tracking so need to add a QS like

```
?utm_source=somesource&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=somecode
```

to my alias.

I tried change it in .htaccess to the following but neither of them work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /contact$
RewriteRule .* /content.php?id=17 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /contact$
RewriteRule .* /content.php?id=17&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

How to catch the query string then?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ content.php?id=17 [L,QSA,NC]
```